# AJAX AutoComplete Extender display result issue

Tags: c#, ajax

I'm using autocomplete extender which is working fine but the returned array is coming in fractional.

I have debugged it via breakpoint. There also it was working fine but on interface the returned result is in decimal.

if i have result 1171210500380120120615191746 then on screen it is displaying 1.1712105003801201e+27

Please help m stuck.